# homogenous transformation matrix variants

Tags: manipulator, dh-parameters

I am working on some manipulator projects and come across a few variants of the homogenous transformation matrix. I've been working on matlab and they give slightly different answers. Assuming both are correct, I would like to ask which one to use and under what circumstances? Are there any conventions that follow along with these trransformation matrices.

[image: variant 1]
[image: variant 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On serial manipulator modelling, we commonly use Denavit-Hartenberg system. One important thing you need to know, there are 2 variant of it, that is Denavit-Hartenberg system and Modified Denavit-Hartenberg. The main difference between two is coordinates system attachment to links and order of performed transformation [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denavit%E2%80%93Hartenberg_parameters)].

- **Denavit-Hartenberg System**
  [image: DH System]

Fig 1. DH Coordinate System Attachment

Will have HTM

[image: DH HTM]

- **Modified Denavit-Hartenberg System**
  [image: MDH System]

Fig 2. MDH Coordinate System Attachment

Will have HTM

[image: MDH HTM]

And both are correct. My professor recommendation was to use MDH because it use less variable to represent manipulator.

Reference :

1. [Denavit Hartenberg Modelling Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denavit%E2%80%93Hartenberg_parameters)

Comment: Thanks! @Albert H M, I found a clearer explanation of the exact differences here. 
https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_modified_DH_parameters_How_will_they_differ_compared_to_DH_parameters#:~:text=%22Standard%22%20DH%20convention%20assumes%20that,at%20the%20i%2B1%20joint.&text=Unlike%20the%20%22standard%22%20DH%20convention,and%20zi%20about%20xi%2D1.